# grep to return value for Referer in trail -f httpd-access.log

Tags: grep

Question is: how can i filter out the http referrer value from `httpd-access.log` file while using `tail -f /var/log/httpd-access.log`

which is usually the third value after the requested url

```
[IP HERE] - - [09/Oct/2016:16:53:12 +0000] "[URL HERE]" 200 283 "[REFERRER_HERE << I NEED THIS ONE]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0"
```

That's an example line from `httpd-access.log`, you see there the `[URL HERE]` which is the real requested url  two not important values (to me), I need the third value to be shown only,

I thought about grep but I lack knowledge there, could it be `grep {something} | tail -f /var/log/httpd-access.log` ?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pipe tail output to grep:

```
$ tail -F /var/log/httpd-access.log | grep 'WHATEVER'
```

You can use `awk` to print a specific column:

```
$ tail -F /var/log/httpd-access.log | grep 'WHATEVER' | awk '{print $9}'
```

Comment: perfect, is there a way to output it like awk $7 = awk $11
to output it like REQUESTED_URL :: REFERRER
"example.com :: example_referrer.com"

Comment: found it with awk '{print $11}  {print $7}', dunno if that's the right approach

Comment: You can use `awk {print $7, $11}` to output multiple columns. You can also use `awk` to do the `grep` job: `awk /WHATEVER/ {print $7, $11}`. Or to match a specific column: `awk $7 ~ /WHATEVER/ {print $7, $11}`.